# OS X: Change sharing-only account to 'normal' account

Tags: macos, user-account

Somehow, OS X changed my main user account to sharing-only. This means that all data in the user folder is still existent on the disk, I can't login to that user. Is there a way to revert a sharing-only user to a normal account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open the Users panel in Preferences
- Unlock the panel (if necessary)
- Right-click on your changed account, select "Advanced Options..."
- Reassign a login shell and a home directory to the user if necessary
- Click on your changed account
- Enable Administrator option
- Wait for the user type changing to Admin in the user list
- Disable Administrator option again

Comment: Would love to know how to "Reassign a login shell"

Comment: @A.K. There should be an input field which allows to select another shell on the "Advanced Options" dialog. If this isn't the case, please ask a new question and include both a screenshot of this dialog and a link to the question here for reference.