# Can I change administrators rights

Tags: terminal

I am admin on OS X 10.11.6.

I would like to change another user's preferences from an Admin to a Standard user.

Ideas anyone - Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: Flagging as unclear.  What does it mean to *change a user from admin to invite ideas*?

Comment: This is also a dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212517/os-x-change-sharing-only-account-to-normal-account/212519#212519

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X: Change sharing-only account to 'normal' account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212517/os-x-change-sharing-only-account-to-normal-account)

Answer (score 2):

The System Preferences application has a "Users & Groups" pane where you can add or remove a user's administrator privileges. You may have to unlock the pane before selecting the user. Next, check or uncheck "Allow user to administer this computer".

[image]