# Change sharing-only account to standard one: how to build the `home` directory?

Tags: macos, user-account

I need to change a sharing-only account to a standard one.

From the **Advanced options** in System Preferences's **Users and Groups** I can choose the login shell and select a home directory, however there is no option to **build** the latter.

**How do I build a home directory for a existing user account?**

I'm on macOS 12.5 Monterey.

---

*Please note*: this question is **different** from [OS X: Change sharing-only account to 'normal' account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212517/84016) because in that case the user's home folder is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make note of the groups and UID and delete, recreate. You likely end up with a new UID and have to script file changes if you use file sharing extensively.

Managing UID is the number one reason LDAP and external directories are adopted rather than making exclusively local accounts.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/set-up-local-macos-accounts-depca092ad96/web

Comment: thank you @bmike it worked well without anything getting screwed up.

Comment: Wonderful, as long as you don’t need to enter into secure token territory, this works well for most cases @Paolo